# Simple Datetime format in form of YYYYMMDD

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with time format
I would like to get an output of the form `YYYY-MM-DD` given the datetime data input as **19901209** which is `1990-12-09`.

I would also like to know if there is any way to get the data in other formats as well, for example, `DD-MM-YYYY` or `MM-DD-YYYY` given the data formated in the form as specified i.e **19901209**.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        string sDate = "19901209";
        string format = "yyyyMMdd";

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = 
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, format, provider); 
        // result holds wanted DateTime
```

Answer (score 10):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("19901209", "yyyyMMdd",null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse a date with a specific format using the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("19901209", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then, you can format it any way you like with the [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method and [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative.
You can divide the string "19901209" in three separate strings like `sYear="1990"`, `sMonth="12"` and `sDate="09"` using `SubString()` method. Then concatenate these strings into a single string like `sNewDate = sYear+"-"+sMonth+"-"+sDate` and then in a `DateTime` variable `dtDate`, formate the string as your need like `DateTime dtDate = Convvert.ToDateTime(sNewDate.ToString("Your Desired Format"));`